# Identifying parameters of Cypher query

Tags: neo4j

Is there an API for identifying the named parameters of a given Cypher query? When taking the following query as example:

```
MATCH (n) WHERE n.firstName = { name } AND n.LastName = { lastName } RETURN n
```

Then this API should return "name" and "lastName".

Does Neo4j provide such an API or would I have to manually parse the query string to identify any parameters it contains?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no API for obtaining the names of the properties used in a Cypher query. There is generally no need for such a utility, since the code making the query should already know that information.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. I'm working on a library (specifically, Hibernate OGM which aims at providing access to NoSQL stores via JPA) and in this particular case I actually do have the need for that functionality. Users of our API may set query parameters and I'd like to validate them (Have all parameters been passed? Have only actually existent parameters been passed?) before passing the query to the datastore.

Comment: There's no public support for anything like that. The only thing I can suggest is that you can catch the ParameterNotFoundException.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can begin your query with parameters in a transaction, get the result/errors and rollback it ?

http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/rest-api-transactional.html